# Link Paypal-Buttons (client) to Server-Response (PHP) with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, paypal, xmlhttprequest, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to use Paypal on my website, so I am following the tutorial [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/#on-the-server).
Everything is working so far: Downloaded the SDK with composer. Created the class `PayPalClient` and `CreateOrder`.

At the end of this section of the tutorial, the result of `CreateOrder` needs to be linked to the Buttons using javascript:

```
    <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function() {
            return fetch('test_paypal_create_paypal_transaction.php', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                return data.orderID;
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
</script>
```

And this is the php file (`test_paypal_create_paypal_transaction.php`):

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use MyProject\PayPay\CreateOrder;

$response = CreateOrder::createOrder(false);
echo json_encode($response);
```

The class `CreateOrder` is working correct. I can out put response from paypal. The issue does not seems to be there.
I can also see in the Firefox-Dev-Tools that the XHR-Request is done correctly, when I press the Paypal-Button. There is also a XHR-Response comming back to the buttons. But it seems I am using the wrong format or wrong part of the data, that is returned into the `fetch()`-Function.

Anybody an idea?

Thanks for help!!!

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

This:

```
[...]
    }).then(function(data) {
        return data.orderID;
    });
[...]
```

needs to be replaced by that:

```
[...]
    }).then(function(data) {
        return data.result.id;
    });
[...]
```